# How to re-size this image to be suitable to the text?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have an image and I want to re-size it to be suitable to the size of the text that will be besides to it. And the Text should be centered according to this image which will be on the left of this text.

**So how to do that?**

(Sorry I can't upload the image because I am a new user and I am not allowed to post images.)

**EDIT:**

Please see an example of what I am talking about [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/matrix388/HDruV/1/)

Comment: Can you post something on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use display:table-cell for both of them in css. Then you should define Text's Vertical Align as middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cY22B/4/

Answer (score 0):

Using a dynamic programming language you could generate code to:

```
<div class="image">
 <img width="350" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="A national flag" />
</div>
<div class="text" style="width:350px;">
 This is the national flag and this is why we are using it.
</div> 
<br class="clear" />
```

Check out the working example on: http://jsfiddle.net/cY22B/